# How to delete the parent div when <i> tag inside button clicked?

Tags: javascript, dom

I am trying to build my to-do list but I am struggling with the delete button.

this is for the button and the code for the eventLisner

```
let deleteButton = document.createElement('button');
deleteButton.innerHTML = '<i class="fa-solid fa-trash-can"></i>';
deleteButton.classList.add('deleteTask');
task.appendChild(deleteButton);
```

and the code for the eventLisner

```
deleteButton.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    let target = e.target;
    target.parentElement.remove();
    });
```

I just want to know how when clicking the  element it deletes the div as the button , now its deleting the button.

Comment: Paste full code with snippet please.

Comment: Add an id or class to the div. If you have a class on the div, you can use `target.closest('.class').remove()`.

Comment: @SimoneRossaini full code link: https://github.com/MohammadKaleaji/kaleaji/blob/main/to-do/app.js

Comment: @MohammadKALEAJI Please read [ask], where it notes, "If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to (for example, on http://sqlfiddle.com/ or http://jsbin.com/) then do so - but also copy the code into the question itself. Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time. Use [Stack Snippets](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992) to make a live demo of inline JavaScript / HTML / CSS."

Comment: @MohammadKALEAJI I paste your code in the snippet and all work..

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use the event's `composedPath()` which includes all the elements/objects that the event bubbles through. Kind of like all the parent chain of the event target until the window object.

What we do is:

1. Convert the compsoed path to an array `[...e.composedPath()]`

   - If we click on `<i></i>` the composed path would be:

     - **i**
     - **button**
     - **div.container**
     - **body**
     - **htmldocument**
     - **Window**
2. Use `Array.prototype.find()` to get the container we're trying to delete.

   - The condition I use is to check for the class `container`
3. Remove the container

The advantage of using `composedPath()` is that the element you're trying to get doesn't have to be the direct parent, or any pre-specified distance from the button.

```js
const deleteButtons = [...document.querySelectorAll('button')]
deleteButtons.forEach(button => 
  button.addEventListener('click', function(e){
     let pathArray = [...e.composedPath()];
     let task = pathArray.find(el => el.classList.contains('container'))
      task.remove();
  })
)
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Task 1</h1>
  <button><i>Delete</i></button>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <h1>Task 2</h1>
  <button><i>Delete</i></button>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <h1>Task 3</h1>
  <button><i>Delete</i></button>
</div>
```